# Add Item templates mssing just for one asp.net core app

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET CORE (core .net) application I received from a colleague.  This app was generated through a Yeoman template on a Mac and built in Visual Studio Code.  When I open the application in Visual Studio 15 and attempt to add a class by using the Add Item dialog, the class item template is missing. As are most of the other add item templates.

However, if I create my own ASP.NET CORE project from Visual Studio 15, the add Item templates are available. This is clearly not a case where the templates are missing overall, so reinstalling the templates is not a solution.

Comparing both xproj files, I really don't see any important difference. Can anyone shed light on how visual studio 15 determines what Add Item templates are available for a project?